# Selenium: Not able to click on an element available in POP up

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am not able to click on an element available in POP up. But when i did gettext() it is working fine(i.e printing right value). Please help and find the screenshot for your reference!!!

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("[objId-cell-1-0][1]"));    
String sss = we.getText();   
System.out.println(sss);     
we.click();
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WGNc.jpg)

HTML Snippet

```
<span id="objId-row-0" class="aw-templates-list aw-text-normal aw-grid-row aw-row-0 aw-rows-normal aw-alternate-even "> 
<span id="objId-row-0-start" class="aw-row-start " style="width:0px;"></span>
<span id="objId-cell-1-0" class="aw-item-template aw-templates-cell aw-grid-cell aw-column-1 aw-cells-normal " title="">Bulk Upload ACT 1</span>
<span id="objId-cell-2-0" class="aw-item-template aw-templates-cell aw-grid-cell aw-column-2 aw-cells-normal " title=""></span> 
<span id="objId-row-0-end" class="aw-item-template aw-grid-cell aw-column-space "> </span>
```

Comment: can you paste your html please? I don't see any screenshots also.

Comment: Dear please find the HTML.....

Comment: <span id="objId-row-0" class="aw-templates-list aw-text-normal aw-grid-row aw-row-0 aw-rows-normal aw-alternate-even ">
<span id="objId-row-0-start" class="aw-row-start " style="width:0px;"></span><span id="objId-cell-1-0" class="aw-item-template aw-templates-cell aw-grid-cell aw-column-1 aw-cells-normal " title="">Bulk Upload ACT 1</span>
<span id="objId-cell-2-0" class="aw-item-template aw-templates-cell aw-grid-cell aw-column-2 aw-cells-normal " title=""></span>
<span id="objId-row-0-end" class="aw-item-template aw-grid-cell aw-column-space ">

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: There is no Exception and test case also get passed but element is not clicked.

Comment: @Ardesco  Can you please help??

Comment: why are you using your xpath as `[objId-cell-1-0][1]` isn't it should only be `[objId-cell-1-0]`

Comment: I used driver.findElement(By.id("objId-cell-1-0")) it is changed due to stack overflow formatting...

Comment: Hey can you give me the url of application? Is it accessible from outside?

Comment: may i have your skype id?? or gmail?? when i can share things related with the same.

Comment: ok join this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/98650/seleniumdiscussion?tab=general

Comment: can you post the details in chatroom?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so can't chat....